# How can I configure a Spring Cloud Config Server with Vault backend to authenticate using the Vault Sidecar Agent

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have an spring boot project config server which uses a vault backend.
application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: vault
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          kvVersion: 2
          order: 1
```

If I start with this config, all the petitions must contain X-Config-Token.
The config server it´s deployed on Kubernetes, with the vault sidecar agent attached to the pod.
On the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#vault-backend

Shows how can I change the authentication type, but doesn't support:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault.config.authentication.vault-agent

```
spring.cloud.vault:
    authentication: NONE
```

To delegate all the auto auth to the agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a composite config with a dummy token, on application.yml:

```
spring:

  profiles:
      active: composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          token: "dummy"
        failOnCompositeError: false
        composite:
        -
          type: vault
          kvVersion: 2
        -
          type: git
          uri: https://-----
```